# IE style completely messed up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, layout

I know IE is sometimes dificult regarding styling like css etc.
But now I have an issue which is over the top!
I dont even know where to begin.

This is Chrome. Its perfect: (Firefox is exactly the same)

[image: chrome perfect delight]

Take a look at IE:

[image: IE terrible mess]

On top of that. In IE I cant even loginbut I think thats another problem.

Doens anybody have tips or something?

Comment: please provide code or a jsfiddle

Comment: Have you run the code through the [W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/)?

Comment: Probably got a broken html element which is causing a knock on effect.

Comment: Looks like you might have missed closing a CSS definition or HTML tag somewhere.

Comment: @HansElsen Is that IE8? Did you use CSS3's border-radius for the rounded edges? For that much it won't work in IE8 or below. There is a solution for that part here, but... a lot of people don't like it:  http://css3pie.com/documentation/supported-css3-features/

Comment: Perhaps missing the `DOCTYPE` so IE is running in Quirks mode?

Answer (score 3):

Add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of your document. Make sure nothing precedes this.

If IE doesn't find a doctype it defaults to Quirks Mode, which is equivalent to an archaic version of Internet Explorer.

Comment: to expand on "make sure nothing precedes this" ... that means *nothing*. No white space, no comments, nothing. `<!DOCTYPE html>` must be the very first thing the browser sees, otherwise IE will destroy your site. (other doctypes are also okay, but if you're not sure, just stick with that one)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is indeed a common problem (+1), but this wasn't my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. I validated the HTML and there were some invalid tags. So stupid that I didn't do this earlier.

Thanks for all the answers. I still have the login problem though, but I'll handle that later.